# Install AppFabric throught Windows installer xml WIX

Tags: windows, wix, appfabric, webdeploy, aspnet-compiler

Does anyone know if AppFabric can be installed through WIX (windows installer xml)

We have an enterprise application we deploy to clients through installer using WIX (windows installer xml)  and this application use AppFabric 1.1 and we need to make our installer to be able to also install the AppFabric on the client server..

I have ve spent 2 days getting familiar with all the stuff about AppFabric but I can find solid information whether it is possible or not..

Does anyone knows if it is feasible ?

Thank you so much and blessings.

Hernán

Answer (score 0):

If AppFabric is normal installer, you can download it from internet using Custom Action (normal way - for example using *WebClient*) and then start installation

```
var process = Process.Start(filePath);
process.WaitForExit();
```

You just have to remember to start it in ***InstallUISequence***! Sample:

```
<Custom Action="ConfigurEwsFilter" After="ExecuteAction" >
  <![CDATA[NOT Installed]]>
</Custom>
```

I heard that bootstrapper can download (or add to installer) and fire file too, but i have never test it :) That's why [Check this tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html)!